# Drag and Drop Metadata Menu Order

Tags: jquery, post-meta, meta-query, jquery-ui

I'm not sure this has been answered previously..

I have a frontend form where the user fills out a form that has dynamic fields where they can add more fields if they choose to.  The jquery names the input fields as follows

data[0]
data[1]
data[2]
data[3]
etc.. depending on how many fields the user wants.

When the form is submitted, all the data goes into one record as metadata. Is there a way to have the user be able to reorder the metadata with a drag and drop functionality?

And save the metadata order?

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex answer, more than can really be answered in a post here.  However, you can take a look at this tutorial - I've done something similar, and his post is very thorough:
 [jQuery UI Sortable Tutorial](http://www.xmech.net/programming/jquery-ui-sortable-tutorial/)